# Testing stored array characters in C

Tags: c

I have just started learning C and I am trying to complete an exercise where I have to remove all the trailing whitespace characters in a line. My logic seem fine to me, but when I try to test if a character is a tab or a space it doesn't come back true, even if it is.

The part with the problem:

```
if ((s[ii] == ' ' || s[ii] == '\t') && trailing == 1)
```

The entire thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

int getline2(char line[], int maxline, char outputLine[]);

/* print above 80 character lines */
main()
{
  char cl;
  char sl[MAXLINE];
  char ol[MAXLINE];
  int i;

  while((cl = getline2(sl, MAXLINE, ol)) > 0){
    if(cl > 1){
      printf("%d: %s", cl, ol);
    }
  }

}
/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline2(char s[], int lim, char ss[])
{
  int c, i, ii;
  for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i){
    s[i] = c;
  }
  int trailing = 1;

  for(ii = i; ii >= 0; ii--){
    if ((s[ii] == ' ' || s[ii] == '\t') && trailing == 1){
      i--;
    } else {
      ss[ii] = s[ii];
      trailing = 0;
    }
  }
  if (c == '\n') {
    ss[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  ss[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Hint: Look at the values, especially `ii` and `s[ii]`,  the very first time that `if` condition runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `for` loop should start from `i - 1`:

```
  for(ii = i - 1; ii >= 0; ii--){
           ^^^^^
```

because in previous `for` loop, `i` is incremented after adding the trailing spaces and tabs in the string `s`.

Comment: Thank you, I think understand. The for loop adds 1 to i, AFTER each successful run, so even if there was no next character (that would go to that index), i would still be incremented by 1

Comment: @Michael No, the loop counter `i` will be incremented after executing the body of loop and if the loop condition fails, `i` will not be incremented. Trace the loop counter `i` for better understanding.